# How to sort after "group by" in a SharePoint Online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, jquery, calculated-column

I have created a list and populated it with some data. I have grouped it with **ID** column. So now it is appearing with count as below :

[image]

Numbers in () are the count of times with same ID.

I want it to sort it with the number of items of each group, as below :

- Action Item Id: 310 (1)
- Action Item Id: 312 (2)
- Action Item Id: 209 (3)

Can you please help me to achieve this.

Comment: can you provide us screenshot? i dont know what you want what means the (1)?

Comment: Added the screenshot in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't short by (1) value, cause this is *dynamically load based on the Group By field* in View.

If you want to Group Items by some field and after this sorting by the Amount of Items in each GroupBy value, **you need to create your own coded Web-Part for this**.